# CTS_ERROR >>> Failed to execute shell command am instrument

Tags: cts

1. Using the Android 2.2, API-8, SDK-r7 along with CTS-2.2_r4 suite.
2. Updated the `SDK_ROOT` environment variable with SDK_r7 tools in `“android-cts/tools/startcts”` script and the `“SDK_ROOT/tools”` also included in `PATH` environment variable.
3. Ran the “android” and created a new virtual device and started the same. This invokes the emulator named as `“emulator-5554”`.
4. Now, started the cts using the below command:

   ```
   bash android-cts/tools/startcts.    
   start –plan android
   ```
5. Above command failed with:

   ```
   Test package: android.app
   install met failure [install_failed_insufficient_storage]
   CTS_ERROR >>> Failed to execute shell command am instrument -w -r -e package android com.android.cts.app/android.test.InstrumentationCtsTestRunner on device emulator-5554
   com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException.
   ```

A few more issues are:

```
CTS_ERROR >>> Got exception while processing command
CTS_ERROR >>> Installing met timeout due to Unknown reason
CTS_ERROR >>> Timeout: ReferenceAppTest
CTS_ERROR >>> Timeout: getDeviceInfo
```

Any hint to avoid the above timeout issues? Thank you very much for anticipating a quick response from you.

Answer (score 0):

I did not got this error on the CTS 2.1 r5. But I am not running the SDK test that Android but my own tests instead. There for I will use the CTS 2.1 for a while.